# Is this dice mechanism calculation question on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, specific-question

[How can I calculate the probability of being able to purchase a card in my custom die system?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103090/23970) has had an interesting life so far:

- closed (3 votes, incl. a diamond mod) as unclear
- bunch of comments asking for clarification on the die-system being described (now moved to chat)
- edits to better explain the system
- (automatically) placed in queue for reopen review, which looks like it was rejected
- migration to B&CG suggested (which I declined, not being sure it'd be on-topic there)
- further editing for readability
- more and more comments about whether it's on- or off-topic
- comment-discussion about how to program it in anydice, moved to chat
- locked
- unlocked
- reopened by 5 regular users
- closed by me, because it sure looks off-topic to me and I'd like to hear why it's on-topic

[this narrative assumes I'm interpreting the "timeline" (*extremely* obscure tool) correctly, which may also be a problem--others please feel free to correct my read!]

So, have at it: on-topic, or off?

---

[update] I've reopened the question to favor a "default: leave it open" policy. Too much waffling--someone should take my hands off the mod-stick!

Comment: @doppelgreener--good edit. I certainly wasn't intending a class-wide ruling, just this particular question.

Comment: The lock-unlock can probably be disregarded: I was isolating certain comments for moving to chat and that was just a precaution while I was doing deleted-undelete gymnastics with the other comments, so it's not really the question's doing.

Comment: Note: the timeline isn't really mod-only as I understand it, it's just that normal users have to use a userscript or manual link-hackery to get to the link. (The first reopen review item was invalidated by SSD's lock, by the timestamps.)

Comment: (That is, https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/103090/timeline shows me a summary of everything pretty much as described.)

Comment: @TuggyNE iiiiiiinteresting--good to know. Will edit accordingly =)

Answer (score 10):

## This question has precedent

BESW asked a question about [probabilities with coins, for the purpose of game design](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/80246/27327), with 33 upvotes and 6 answers. That Q received no VTC's or controversy, but it is effectively the same type of question as this Q under fire: *I am designing a game with randomness built in, what are the probabilities for this aspect of it?*

WrongOnTheInternet has asked about a [purely statistics-type question concerning exploding dice](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/55720/what-is-the-average-roll-of-a-die-with-an-expanded-explosion-threshold-as-compar), receiving 11 upvotes and 3 highly technical answers, but is again on the same lines: *I am designing a system, but how do I calculate the probabilities?*

HeyICanChan asked about calculating the [probabilities with Anydice on a dice-based system based on multiple types of dice](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37270/how-can-i-examine-the-distribution-of-successes-counting-mixed-dice-pools), which is a Q along similar lines: *here is a system, how can I calculate the probabilities?*

A new user has also asked for a mostly similar Q about [formulas for permutations](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99386/is-this-the-right-formula-for-the-total-permutations-of-a-set-of-dice), another new user asked for [help about using Anydice](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64437/help-calculating-opposing-dice-pool-in-anydice), another new user asks about [exploding dice probabilities](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49710/dice-pool-success-probability-with-one-exploding-die). All three of these questions have in common that they are not attached to any specific gaming system, and are actually purely statistics-based questions.

If this one Q is off-topic, the the six listed above should also be closed, for consistency's sake.

## These types of Q's are on-topic

Leaning on historical precedent, there has been no push back for the above six questions in terms of VTC's. Nothing has changed about the sites policies about these types of statistics Q's in the intervening time, and so since those 6 Q's did not receive the VTC or on/off-topic controversy, this Q shouldn't be off-topic either.

While the Q is not about a problem in the sense of "X happened, what do I do?" or a rules clarification for an RPG system (the typical questions), it is still a Q related to an RPG -- just an unpublished, untested one.

Finally, the presence of the statistics tag allows these types of questions to be asked. If a policy change happens, then we will have to move the statistics tag to be off-topic as well, in the same way that shopping questions were made off-topic.

Comment: So I'm with you that there's precedent, but it seems like there's a little dodging of the actual question: yes, *if* those are on topic than this one is, but do you have a feeling/argument for those/this being on topic or not?

Comment: @nitsua60 I think it's on topic, and updated my A to reflect that

Comment: For obvious reasons, I agree and upvoted this answer, but I think it's fair to say that taking such questions to *Math SE* or elsewhere seems a heavy-handed intervention that unhooks the unasked question — *Is this a reasonable RPG mechanic?* — from this site's users area of expertise. An answer that addresses *How can I compute this?* and *also* explains what impact those probabilities have on the RPG should be found superior to those that don't address the latter. (That's what makes [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/100137/8610) to my question particularly good, for instance.)

Comment: *Mere* statistics and dice probabilities questions are still off topic — we don't want to become a magnet for stats/dice questions with nothing to do with RPGs — but I would agree that the (clarified) RPG context of the question redeems it just enough to belong here.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie That would make the last 3 example Q's off-topic. Two of them are a few years old already though, and one was recently asked

Comment: @markovchain Would it? It seems that the emergent intelligence of collective voting hasn't detected a topic problem with them.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The last 3 Q's are purely stats questions, with no ties to any RPG system. The emergent intelligence of collective voting hasn't detected a problem with them, which means they are fine. Therefore, questions that are purely about stats, with no ties to any RPG questions, are fine. I am contradicting what you said, specifically: "*Mere* statistics and dice probabilities questions are still off topic" because if you are correct, then you must also declare the last 3 Q's off-topic and claim the emergent intelligence of collective voting had it wrong, thrice.

Comment: The emergent intelligence isn't perfect and I'm not claiming it is. What I'm saying is that you can't blatantly contradict our help pages about topicality in order to construct your argument. If there are unclosed questions that you think violate our topic rules, then there is an excluded middle error in your reasoning, because you're overlooking part of the system or oversimplifying the model we actually use. Do not use them to construct arguments that satisfy simplistic first-order logic while violating higher-order pragmatics. (And if you think they're off topic — vote so.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I am pointing out the error in your reasoning. On the one hand, you said that class of questions are off-topic. On the other, you (not I) endorsed the emergent intelligence, which says there was no problem with those last three Q's. Those two positions are incompatible. I happen to think they are on-topic. As the one between us who believes those last three Q's, which fall under the category of "mere statistics and dice probabilities questions," as being off topic, I believe it is you who must consider your vote.

Comment: @markovchain Excluded middle error. You are arguing that either “*mere* statistics and dice probabilities questions”, or that those questions should be forcefully closed. You're ignoring several possibilities that allow both things to be compatible in the moment, such as these two: that open/close state is changeable and rarely/never 100% aligned with what the open/close status of the whole site's questions *should* be if the site were static; that your own judgement is not ruling on their close state, and you might be wrong (your judgement is only ruling on your decision to close vote).

Comment: Consider this: it is axiomatic that ***mere*** statistics and dice probabilities questions are off topic. If you think that those questions are on-topic but violate that axiom, then either your understanding of our topic scope is in error, or you need to revise your judgement of their on-topic-ness and vote them closed.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I couldn't clearly understand what you were saying on your lengthier reply. I am saying that these two are mutually exclusive: "the last three Q's are mere stats questions, and therefore off topic" and "the collective intelligence has not seen a problem with the last three Q's, and thus sees them as on-topic." Either the last three Q's are off topic, or the collective intelligence was wrong. You seemed to endorse both of these mutually exclusive ideas. Let me ground this in something concrete. Do you agree that the last three Q's are mere stats questions?

Comment: @markovchain This isn't binary; I see them as troubling borderline questions that cause problems for out sense of topicality, which I expect will take a while to shake out decisively. (The collective intelligence is not always fast.) This situation is too complex to apply simple propositional logic to, as it is insufficiently expressive to capture the state of the site and policy. (Properly modelling it would require jumping several orders of logic up to pragmatics, but we don't have time to actually model it rigorously. Just: propositional logic is too weak here.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Let me try evidence-based logic. The oldest of those three Q's is almost 3 years old. You seem to be implying the collective intelligence has not yet decided on the validity of those questions. Consider that almost 3 years ago, a question of a certain family was asked. Two months ago, another question under the same family was asked. Both of them were treated the same way each time: no votes for closure. Is this not a long enough time span? Is the collective intelligence still deciding? Is the collective decision to not close indicative of how it views this family of questions?

Comment: @markovchain That's not out of the norm for a low-traffic subtopic on the site. Being old is actually not correlated with being on-topic either: check some of our oldest questions, and you'll see that many were closed years later. We refine our understanding of the site's topic scope constantly, and get closer to best practices by doing so. If dice/stats questions have now hit a critical mass that many users are questioning them, then what's likely (from experience) is that a community re-evaluation of existing and future dice/stats questions is approaching.

Comment: It remains however, that this all comes from and down to one statement that you objected to but I would like you to accept as axiomatic: *mere* statistics and dice probabilities questions are off topic, emphasis on “mere” — we're not “Dice and Stats SE” or even “RPGs and Dice/Stats SE”. Our topic scope is exclusively RPGs, so everything (axiomatically) must be about RPGs. If there is anything that doesn't accord with that, it's not the axiom that you ought to be challenging, and it's elsewhere that the community is (at some point) going to look for misalignments to fix.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Mirroring your words, the situation is too complex to apply simple propositional logic to. You ask me to accept as an axiom that *mere* stats/dice questions are off topic, but what is an example of that? To me, those last three Q's *are* mere stats/dice questions. You looked at them and you have a different perspective. So clearly, your "mere dice/stats Q's" is different from my "mere dice/stats Q's."

Comment: If I accepted or rejected that axiom, it would mean nothing, since we don't seem to agree on what to agree on. I asked you to evaluate those last three Q's, but your reluctance to evaluate them leaves me unable to establish a baseline for what is a "mere stats/dice question" in this discussion. In the absence of that baseline, my acceptance/rejection of the axiom is not meaningful at this moment.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie The best I can provide you is, I believe those last three Q's are on topic, and I believe they are mere stats/dice Q's. But it seems that what a *mere* stats/dice Q is, is unclear and ill-defined, leaving me unable to accept that all mere stats/dice Q's are off topic. What is a mere stats/dice Q to me is evidently not, to you, and by extension, possibly to other users of the site.

Comment: You misunderstand my reluctance to opine on those 3 Qs, and assigned the reluctance propositional value. My reluctance to pass judgement on those questions is as a ♦ moderator. (My opinion on their topicality is complex, confounded by community-management issues too nuanced to get into.) However, I can say that, axiomatically, non-negotiably, as a moderator representing the site's 7-year history: **mere dice and stats questions are absolutely off topic**. If you think there's a problem attached to that, please raise it as a meta; alternatively, vote and/or meta-propose those Qs be closed.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It remains that we don't agree or have an example of what a "mere stats/dice question" looks like for both of us. Your reluctance to judge those last 3 Q's is preventing me from accepting your axiom, because you're asking me to accept something that I don't understand due to lack of data. I am looking at a thing and claiming it is X, and you look at it and you cannot agree. Therefore, is it really X? For me, it is X, but evidently, we don't agree what X is. You then ask me to accept that X is Y. But if I don't know what X is, how can I accept X is Y?

Comment: Okay, I'm not asking anymore then, I'm telling. It's a fundamental fact that questions here must be about RPGs. If you see anything in the site that gives you doubt that that is the case, remember that it's non-negotiable. Everything else proceeds from that—regardless of whether you can corner a mod into giving an Official Opinion on something or not.

Comment: (As for why I refuse to be cornered: I'm not about to give an opinion just to find myself confronted by "well then why don't you close them???" Because why and when mods override the community is not that simplistic.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie In that case, the discussion is closed. I appreciate that you are being mindful about taking mod actions, and I know your hands are tied when taking Official Action. I wasn't going to confront you with that, unless you would ask me outright to VTC those last thee Q's myself. And if your opinion was those last 3 Q's are off topic, you could raise a Q on meta about them -- a gentler approach than outright closing some Q's. Anyway, this isn't useful. You were holding back a concern based on an assumption on what I would say, and it stifled a true discussion.

Comment: As I said, my opinion on those questions is *complicated*. There's more than just mod concerns involved — there's also that I'm judging them by a standard that isn't binary (a long time using the site will do that). My direct concern is that your opinion on those question *is* simple and binary, and clearly makes them off topic by how you describe them, and yet you're saying they're on topic. So clearly there's a problem with how we (the site) is communicating what is and isn't on topic regarding these questions.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I think the fact that my "simple and binary" opinion doesn't perfectly fit with your expectation (that I don't subscribe to X is Y because what X is, is unclear), makes my opinion more complex than you give it credit for. And the site is probably not communicating what is or isn't on topic for this family of questions. As you said, it takes a while for the collective intelligence to sort itself out for a low traffic subtopic. What would help with this (mis)communication is a clear and concrete example of what X is: the same standard we impose of every querent to avoid vagueness.

Comment: I've been trying to say, but you keep rejecting it by second-guessing its plain meaning: mere stats/dice questions are off topic. From what you've said, it's obvious to me that those words mean exactly the same thing to you and me, but you keep insisting that I must mean something other than those plain words because I won't answer your questions out those 3 Qs. As I said, my reluctance to opine on them is orthogonal and has no relation to those plain words, and they mean just what you think they mean. So: we have a plain definition of what's off topic that we evidently both agree on.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I don't think we agree on it at all. I've expended a very considerable effort to make my case. They are not plain words. The situation is too complex to model with propositional logic: your words. Insisting the same thing without listening to feedback is not going to produce different results. My opinion is complicated on this matter, yours appears to be simple. I have left an answer on the meta Q you opened, perhaps a long answer can illustrate my nuanced stance on the matter better.

Comment: *A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds* ~Emerson.  While an appeal to consistency is foolish by default *penalty flag, five yards* for "appeal to consistency" as the basis of argument.  It came off as "if  I (we) can't have (X) then nobody can have (Y) that is similar to (X)" {ref final sentence of first section}.  I am not invested in any side of this argument, but am uncomfortable with that particular tool / appeal being used.  That said, this question and SSD's related meta potentially inform site policy -- in that sense a desire for consistent policy is fair.

Comment: FWIW my view is that the question is on topic.

Answer (score 2):

When I edited the question to be readable there was no indication that the system had any significant relation to an RPG at all.  The OP said in the post at that point:

> OK working on a dice game as part of an in game system where players can play a dice Game that requires a players roll specific results in order to gain a card,
>
> Ok its a game within a game

This plus the content of the game made it appear that the game mechanics asked about had no bearing on the RPG they were being played in at all.  The question, as it appeared, was "How can I get probabilities for this card game I'm developing?" with the only RPG context being that the OP was planning on having the people playing an RPG with them play this card game, too.  The question did not and does not invite commentary on how to integrate such a game or anything like that, it is and was solidly about the probabilities of a card game.

This differentiated it from arbitrary questions about statistics, in my mind.  Were the mechanics intended for use in an RPG (as the OP's answer here indicates) our expertise would be applicable, and we could talk about the stochastic characteristics of this method in the context of its use in RPG conflict resolution (well, somebody could.  [I have trouble doing that with non-math terms](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/99412/)).

When we ask a question about arbitrary statistics on this site, it is understood that we are asking about those statistics in an RPG context.  That context is necessary for the questions to be on-topic, and the principle of good faith tells us we should assume that's the context the question is in unless there is strong evidence to the contrary.  If somebody asks "Are sequential coin flips good random bytestring generators?" here, it's appropriate to respond with "No, because that takes way too much table time", because we're answering from an RPG context.

Now, questions about using tools primarily used for RPGs are, in my opinion, also on-topic here.  We have the experts to be able to answer such questions to a high standard, because the experts in those tools have that expertise as an extension of their RPG expertise.  Dice are a tool we use extensively, but dice are also used extensively outside RPGs.  Asking about dice in general should be on-topic, I think, since they are ubiquitous and quintessential RPG tools, but asking about dice in the specific context of a non-RPG (like, 'what are the odds of me being able to take this space in Risk') is *not* on topic.  This is kinda weird because the underlying question of 'what are the odds that A beats B with this weird dice pool mechanic?' *would*  be on-topic, but somehow because that pool is called 'playing the board game Risk' it becomes off topic.  I'm not sure that this division is *fair* but it is the division that seems most appropriate to me.

Questions about a Board or Card game with no significant RPG context shouldn't be on topic here, even if they are just a question of statistics, even though general questions about statistics with no context are on topic.

That said, the OP made it clear here that these mechanics are intended to be used in the actual game system as well, so I'll edit the question to mention that (since the OP still hasn't), and it should be open.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the same mechanics for both systems one for an custom RPG and the Card game for an in game game in the RPG, as the mechanics for the card game are a simpler function of a more complex system, using them to work-up with the game.
 Just one is not intending to ask how to fully develop the dice mechanics on the full rpg as that misses the point of asking for help to understand the basics so that can upscale with main game. The Question originally did explain that it was for a both an In game RPG Card game, but was edited down and removed due to the question being to verbose.
 However it does raise an interesting point about having the 'Anydice' tag and covering Anydice issues, If it is a matter of moving away, then having a Stack Exchange dedicated to AnyDice might work better.

Comment: Yeah, given this explanation I think it's on topic, if not the best fit. This is a pure ol' math/probability question, and you'll get a better answer to it on a more relevant Stack, but being on topic on another stack doesn't make it off topic here (neither does something not being on topic on any other Stack make it on topic here). I'd reopen it.

Comment: @mxyzplk I wonder how this compares with our "campaign research" question policy? I mean, "pure ol' math/probability" doesn't seem to require RPG expertise, either? However, I know *I* would like questions like these to be on-topic, so perhaps its time for a class-wide meta on statistics/probability topicality?

Comment: Well, that's a good point.  While e.g. desktop publishing is on topic inasumuch as it applies to RPGs, there's a Venn diagram of whether something really benefits from RPG expertise or not - this one certainly doesn't.

Comment: In any case, I think this meta about a specific question isn't the right place to hash out the entire class--I've reopened the specific question and have it on my scratch-list to work on a meta that discusses the whole class. Personally, I'm happy having the questions on-site, but I think it'd be good for lots of eyes to see arguments for why these might be on-topic when others are off-.

Comment: @nitsua60 You probably already know this, but this issue has been discussed [twice](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1028/15469) [before](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3401/15469).